# Are there cases where type assertions and type annotations are equivalent in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

The use of type assertions is often [not recommended](https://medium.com/swlh/why-you-should-avoid-type-assertions-in-typescript-5494e3d04dd) and [considered harmful](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#assertion-considered-harmful).

That makes complete sense to me for complex types like for example this `Person` type where we could run into issues with the `person2` object because we might expect it to have an `age` property which it doesn't (but `person1` correctly gives us a TypeScript error):

```
type Person = { name: string, age: number };

// type annotation
const person1: Person = { name: 'Victoria' };
// type assertion
const person2 = { name: 'Victoria' } as Person;
```

But I'm wondering whether there are cases where there's no difference between a type assertion and a type annotation.

Is there a difference between a type assertion and a type annotation in the following three cases? And/Or are there other cases?

1. For primitive types like `string`, `number`?

   ```
   // type annotation
   const val1: string = 'foo';
   // type assertion
   const val2 = 'foo' as string;
   ```
2. For Arrays of primitive types like `string[]`, `number[]`?

   ```
   // type annotation
   const values1: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
   // type assertion
   const values2 = ['foo', 'bar'] as string;
   ```
3. In case of `any` or `any[]`

   ```
   // type annotation
   const val1: any = 'foo';
   const values1: any[] = ['foo', 1];
   // type assertion
   const val2 = 'foo' as any;
   const values2 = ['foo', 1] as any[];
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *might* be an opinion question because it really depends on what you mean by "equivalent".  Is riding in a car without wearing a seat belt "equivalent" to riding with one, if you don't get into an accident?

---

[Type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) will generally only allow you to assign a value of some type `A` to a variable of some type `B` where `A extends B`.  We say that `A` is [*assignable*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#subtype-vs-assignment) to `B`, and while there are some exceptions and fiddly details, you can think of that as `A` is a *subtype* of `B`, or that `A` is the same as or *narrower* than `B`.  Such assignments are **relatively safe** in TypeScript (although since TypeScript's type system isn't fully [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), they still allow some unsafe things).

So `let foo: string | number = "hello"` works because you are assigning a value of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) `"hello"` (or possibly a value of type `string`) to a variable of type `string | number`, and the former is a subtype of the latter.  You can also write `let bar: 123 = 123` because the literal type `123` is a subtype of itself (subtypes are not required to be "proper" or "strict" subtypes).  But you cannot write `let baz: string = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "baz" : 123;` without error.  The type `"baz" | 123` or `string | number` is not a subtype of `string`.

---

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), on the other hand, allow you to assign a value of some type `A` to a variable of some type `B` where `A extends B` or where `B extends A`.  (Again, there are some complications I'm glossing over here).  All the compiler cares about is that it sees `A` and `B` as "related" to each other.  So you'll only get an error if you try to make an assignment where the two types are unrelated like `let foo = "hello" as number`, and you can always work around this by asserting to an intermediate related type first like `let bar = "hello" as unknown as number`.

Anyway, the `A extends B` direction where you *widen* `A` to `B` is relatively safe and acts similarly to a type annotation, but `B extends A` where you *narrow* `A` to `B` is **unsafe**.  Such narrowing assertions should only be used in cases where you really want the compiler to treat the value it thinks is an `A` as a value of type `B`, even though it cannot verify that.  But you're not talking about the "unsafe" direction right now.

So annotations and *widening* assertions should be mostly "equivalent", right?

---

Well, sure, kind of, as long as nothing changes.  One thing a type annotation does for you is provide a warning if your code changes later and the assigned value suddenly violates the annotated type:

```
const myValue = "foo";

// ... intervening code

const val1: string = myValue; // okay
const val2 = myValue as string; // no error
val2.toUpperCase();
```

If someone comes along later and edits the code so that

```
const myValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "foo" : 123;
```

Then the annotation will catch the problem at compile time:

```
const val1: string = myValue; // error
```

But the assertion happily lets you continue with no problem until runtime:

```
const val2 = myValue as string; // no error!
val2.toUpperCase(); // 50% chance of runtime error
```

This is why I think of type assertions as removing your seat belt (maybe a single assertion is just *loosening* it, while doing the double `a as unknown as B` is taking it off completely).  Everything is fine... until it isn't.  If you knew with 100% certainty ahead of time that you would not get into a car accident, then there's no difference.  (But do you *really* know this?)

If you are sure that your assertion is widening and not narrowing, then it is mostly "equivalent" to an annotation (but are you *really* sure about this?).  In general, though, I'd recommend annotations over widening assertions.

---

There is *one* situation I can think of where a widening assertion is *not* equivalent to an annotation.  When you assign a value of type `A` to a variable of type `B` where `B` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type, the compiler will use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to temporarily narrow the *apparent* type of `B`:

```
let foo: string | number = "foo";
foo.toUpperCase(); // no error, foo has been temporarily narrowed to string
foo = 456; // no error, foo was annotated as string | number
foo.toFixed(); // no error, foo was reset and has been temporarily narrowed to number
```

but assertions don't work this way:

```
let bar = "foo" as string | number;
bar.toUpperCase(); // error! bar was never narrowed
bar = 456 as string | number;
bar.toFixed(); // error!
```

Quite often you prefer the control-flow narrowing behavior and so you'd still want an annotation instead of an assertion.  Sometimes, though, the compiler will be more aggressive than you'd like:

```
let baz: string | number = "baz" // this might be a number sometime but for testing it's "baz"
if (typeof baz === "number") {
    baz.toFixed(); // error?! toFixed() doesn't exist on type 'never'
}
```

Here I've set `baz` to `"baz"` but I would prefer the compiler to think of it as `string | number`.  Because it noticed that it is just `string`, it gets very upset that I might test it for being a `number` and then treat it like one.  A widening assertion can deal with cases like this:

```
let qux = "qux" as string | number;
if (typeof qux === "number") {
    qux.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KSM2lABiWAAHpHKfaM3jswncwl0NBlXEtu6MV7gD6IH6A0GQ6BeTgI1HStq9RgAUglQxdYHDTc+CXMSkkBWqxhxJIt+hzWSrRS7ek8fikBekD2MhANPzZ+HI5Nn7xkym+5lkey7VmeVAXiSjYtvobb3nOBJrhuT4gAAXmqSSaqBBq8HwW6oXu6SrFgCRgFg2grJuyAgNh-JQDsypcsguocCqeTjvQThYHQADkCR4WhfCTFKSD1HQTBVCyKGoc43C4ZWK7oHwjRIGQkjnmhUHNq2d6wghFyPg22mwSp2zQMAPEMBATYkQweA+hJyA8UQH48ZMQqSMhACOHBNoaPlNnuGLAceingZQIliY5UkBbJ8knkpKlqeplABVpMFwd4fgBJIQqkK0QA)